# ODI connection to Snowflake using JDBC driver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connectivity, oracle-data-integrator

I followed all the steps mentioned for ODI to connect to Snowflake and I am able to connect 'without agent'

I also 'unset' the SSL/TLS parameter using code below but still ODI is not able to connect to Snowflake when I use ODI Agent
`ODI_SSL_PROPERTIES=""`

what else I should try?

Error that I get when using ODI Agent is:

```
oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.InvocationException: oracle.odi.core.exception.OdiRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not load JDBC driver class [net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver]
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:475)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.support.InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:162)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invokeTestDataServer(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:1988)
    at com.sunopsis.graphical.dialog.SnpsDialogTestConnet.remoteTestConn(SnpsDialogTestConnet.java:1023)
    at com.sunopsis.graphical.dialog.SnpsDialogTestConnet$12.doInBackground(SnpsDialogTestConnet.java:981)
    at oracle.odi.ui.framework.AbsUIRunnableTask.run(AbsUIRunnableTask.java:258)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.run(ProgressBar.java:961)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: There is a similar issue that is posted here : https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-ODI-12c-Standalone-Agent-Connection-to-Snowflake#:~:text=To%20begin%20setting%20up%20a,for%20use%20by%20the%20agent.

But, from the error it seems that ODI agent has not picked up the snowflake driver. Where is the driver placed and is it included in the path for ODI agent?

Comment: Thanks @SrinathMenon yes that link has the same steps I made. But I was able to fix it based on Oracle SR. They asked me to put the jdbc driver in one more location under/sdk/lib folder and added it in one of the python scripts and restarted the agent which did the trick for me :)